# How to create line chart, with custom data points and line style in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, linechart

I was wondering if I could use some javascript library like [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/), [gRaphaeljs](http://g.raphaeljs.com/), [flotcharts](http://www.flotcharts.org/), or [d3js](http://d3js.org/) to create a chart like the following:
[image]

It has custom circle in more of like a donut shape and the line style I want it to be like connecting dots on a picture. As you can see in the image, the lines have a small margin between each point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use Google Chart for this. I admit I tried it just out of curiosity but it does work. All you have to do is draw chart with standard round points and then when chart is finished (on ready event) add shapes of your own:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function(){
     // Looping thru every standard point
     $('circle').each(function() {
                  var $c = $(this);

        // addinng outer circle                      
        var circles = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
        circles.setAttribute("cx",$c.attr('cx'));
        circles.setAttribute("cy",$c.attr('cy'));
        circles.setAttribute("r",$c.attr('r'));
        circles.setAttribute("fill",$c.attr('fill'));
        circles.setAttribute("stroke",'white');                  
        circles.setAttribute("stroke-width",'3');                  
        this.parentElement.appendChild(circles);

        // addinng inner circle                                            
        circles = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
        circles.setAttribute("cx",$c.attr('cx'));
        circles.setAttribute("cy",$c.attr('cy'));
        circles.setAttribute("r", "4");
        circles.setAttribute("fill","white");
        this.parentElement.appendChild(circles);                  
  })

});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/focnsyu9/1/**

Comment: thank you!! i was also wondering is there any site I could use as a guide or tutorial to learn how to customize graphs like you did?

Comment: @nommer I don't think there's a specific tutorial, you have to sort of look into how things work. I haven't used either Google Charts or SVG much, but I ran their sample saw that it produced SVG circles as points and simple added to the picture.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter thank it works fine, but in my case i want to apply it on specific chart not for all, can it possible that visualization apply only on specific one .

Answer (score 1):

Check out charts.js line charts. http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart